# How to specify the parent query field from within a subquery in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, parent-child

**How do I specify the parent query field from within a subquery in MySQL?**

For Example:
I have written a basic Bulletin Board type program in PHP.

In the database each post contains: id(PK) and parent_id(the id of the parent post).  If the post is itself a parent, then its parent_id is set to 0.

I am trying to write a mySQL query that will find every parent post and the number of children that the parent has.

```
$query = "SELECT id, (
      SELECT COUNT(1) 
      FROM post_table 
      WHERE parent_id = id
) as num_children
FROM post_table
WHERE parent_id = 0";
```

The tricky part is that the first **id** doesn't know that it should be referring to the second *id* that is outside of the subquery.  I know that I can do SELECT id AS id_tmp  and then refer to it inside the subquery, but then if I want to also return the id and keep "id" as the column name, then I'd have to do a query that returns me 2 columns with the same data (which seems messy to me)

```
$query = "SELECT id, id AS id_tmp, 
            (SELECT COUNT(1)
            FROM post_table
            WHERE parent_id = id_tmp) as num_children
         FROM post_table
         WHERE parent_id = 0";
```

The messy way works fine, but I feel an opportunity to learn something here so I thought I'd post the question.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

How about:

```
$query = "SELECT p1.id, 
                 (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                    FROM post_table p2 
                   WHERE p2.parent_id = p1.id) as num_children
            FROM post_table p1
           WHERE p1.parent_id = 0";
```

or if you put an alias on the p1.id, you might say:

```
$query = "SELECT p1.id as p1_id, 
                 (SELECT COUNT(1) 
                    FROM post_table p2 
                   WHERE p2.parent_id = p1.id) as num_children
            FROM post_table p1
           WHERE p1.parent_id = 0";
```

Comment: what if i have taken alias for p1.id ?

Comment: What does that mean? "taken alias for"?

Comment: If I have taken alias like : "SELECT p1.id as MYID," then what will be the query?

Comment: @Er.KT, I have made an edit to the answer showing an alias on id as well.

Comment: ohk got it,so we dont have to pass alias in subquery condition (WHERE p2.parent_id = p1.id (not 'p1_id' here)),right?

Comment: Yup, that is right, the alias is as the word implies, an additional name, not a replacement name.

Comment: Will this same solution work for subqueries that are part of a join rather than the field selectors? i.e. JOIN (SELECT <some field> FROM table2 WHERE p1.id = p2.parent_id)
I keep getting an error saying "Unknown column p1.id" (actual string is bi.id) and bi.id is a table alias set in the from clause of the p1 parent query.

Answer (score 7):

You could try something like this

```
SELECT  pt.id,
        CountTable.Cnt
FROM    post_table pt LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT  parent_id,
                    COUNT(1) Cnt
            FROM    post_table
            WHERE   parent_id <> 0
            GROUP BY parent_id
        ) CountTable ON pt.id = CountTable.parent_id
WHERE   pt.parent_id = 0
```

To get back to your example, use the *alias* of the main table in the sub select

```
SELECT  pt.id,
        (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM post_table WHERE parent_id = pt.id) 
FROM    post_table pt
WHERE   pt.parent_id = 0
```

Answer (score 4):

Give the tables unique names:

```
$query = "SELECT a.id, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM post_table b WHERE parent_id = a.id) as num_children FROM post_table a WHERE a.parent_id = 0";
```

Answer (score 1):

The following syntax works in Oracle. Can you test if the same works in MYSQL too?
It is called scalar subquery in Oracle.

You would just need to alias the two tables differently to distinguish between them if you are using the same table twice.

```
sql> select empno,
  2         (select dname from dept where deptno = emp.deptno) dname
  3    from emp 
  4    where empno = 7369;

     EMPNO DNAME
---------- --------------
      7369 RESEARCH

sql> select parent.empno,
  2         (select mgr from emp where empno = parent.empno) mgr
  3    from emp parent
  4    where empno = 7876;

     EMPNO        MGR
---------- ----------
      7876       7788
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Don. I had a nested query as shown below and a `WHERE` clause in it wasn't able to determine alias `v1`.  Here is the code which isn't working:

```
Select 
    teamid,
    teamname
FROM
    team as t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        venue_id, 
        venue_scores, 
        venue_name 
    FROM venue 
    WHERE venue_scores = (
        SELECT 
            MAX(venue_scores) 
        FROM venue as v2 
        WHERE v2.venue_id = v1.venue_id      /* this where clause wasn't working */
    ) as v1    /* v1 alias already present here */
);
```

So, I just added the alias `v1` again inside the `JOIN`. Which made it work.

```
Select 
    teamid,
    teamname
FROM
    team as t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        venue_id, 
        venue_scores, 
        venue_name 
    FROM venue as v1              /* added alias v1 here again */
    WHERE venue_scores = (
        SELECT 
            MAX(venue_scores) 
        FROM venue as v2 
        WHERE v2.venue_id = v1.venue_id   /* Now this works!! */
    ) as v1     /* v1 alias already present here */
);
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

### Parent query field within a subquery in MySQL 8.

**I'm selecing games scores on the basis of username from tblgamescores using nested query.**

```
SELECT 
    GameScoresID, 
    (SELECT Username FROM tblaccounts WHERE AccountID = FromAccountID) AS FromUsername, 
    (SELECT Username FROM tblaccounts WHERE AccountID = ToAccountID) AS ToUsername,
    (SELECT Username FROM tblaccounts WHERE AccountID = WinAccountID) AS WinUsername,
    (SELECT Username FROM tblaccounts WHERE AccountID = LossAccountID) AS LossUsername,
    FromUserScore,
    ToUserScore 
FROM tblgamescores a 
WHERE FromAccountID = (SELECT AccountID FROM tblaccounts WHERE Username = "MHamzaRajput");
```