# Referencing previous table in join / subselect

Tags: mysql

I'm usually very smart in writing even complex queries but I sometimes get stuck on really easy things like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM
orders o
JOIN (
    SELECT i.order_id, COUNT(*) AS order_item_count
    FROM order_item i WHERE i.order_id = o.order_id
) x
ON x.order_id = o.order_id
```

> `#1054 - Unknown column 'o.order_id' in 'where clause'`

**How can I reference the order_id inside the subselect?**

What I **don't** want to do:

```
SELECT * FROM
orders o
JOIN order_item i WHERE i.order_id = o.order_id
ON i.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

I have multiple tables to join and I want the order_id not put inside a GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my question beeing a duplicate of [How to specify the parent query field from within a subquery in mySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973246/how-to-specify-the-parent-query-field-from-within-a-subquery-in-mysql)

So its solution is to put the subselect in the fields area rather than to join the subdataset:

```
SELECT
   *,
   (SELECT COUNT(i.order_id)
    FROM order_item i
    WHERE i.order_id = o.order_id) AS order_item_count
FROM orders o
```