# SQL query on large tables fast at first then slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Below query returns the initial result fast and then becomes extremely slow.

```
SELECT A.Id
, B.Date1
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.Id = B.Id AND A.Flag = 'Y'
AND (B.Date1 IS NOT NULL AND A.Date >= B.Date2 AND A.Date < B.Date1)
```

Table A has 24 million records and Table B has 500 thousand records.

Index for Table A is on columns: Id and Date

Index for Table B is on columns: Id, Date2, Date1 - Date1 is nullable - index is unique

Frist 11m records are returned quite fast and it then suddenly becomes extremely slow. Execution Plan shows the indexes are used.

However, when I remove condition A.Date < B.Date1, query becomes fast again.

Do you know what should be done to improve the performance? Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I updated the query to show that I need fields of Table B in the result. You might think why I used left join when I have condition "B.Date1 is not null". That's because I have posted the simplified query. My performance issue is even with this simplified version.

Comment: Which version of SQL server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 r2

Comment: I'm wondering if the complicated join condition means that the cardinality estimator can't guess the right number of rows, therefore you're getting a poor execution plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can maybe try using `EXISTS`. It should be faster as it stops looking for further rows once a match is found unlike `JOIN` where all the rows will have to be fetched and joined.

```
select id
from a
where flag = 'Y'
    and exists (
        select 1
        from b
        where a.id = b.id
            and a.date >= b.date2
            and a.date < b.date1
            and date1 is not null
        );
```

Comment: for simplicity i eliminated most of my query. based on your approach how can I use fields of table b in main select.

Comment: @Bob - If that's the case, your own query will do. Regarding performance comparison of with and without filter `A.Date < B.Date1`, you can't really compare the two as they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what I've noticed with queries, and SQL performance is the DATA you are joining, for instance `ONE to ONE` relationships are much faster than `ONE to MANY` relationships.

I've noticed `ONE to MANY` relationship on table `3000` items, joining to a table with `30,000` items can easily take up to 11-15 seconds, with `LIMIT`. But that same query, redesigned with all `ONE TO ONE` relationships would take less than 1 second.

So my suggestion to speed up your query.
According to [Left Outer Join (desc)](http://www.dofactory.com/sql/left-outer-join) *"LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN are the same"* so it doesn't matter which one, you use.

But ideally, should use `INNER` because in your question you stated `B.Date1 IS NOT NULL`

Based on this [parent columns in join selection (desc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973246/how-to-specify-the-parent-query-field-from-within-a-subquery-in-mysql), you can use parent column in SELECT within JOIN.

```
SELECT a.Id FROM A a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT b.Id AS 'Id', COUNT(1) as `TotalLinks` FROM B b WHERE ((b.Date1 IS NOT NULL) AND ((a.Date >= b.Date2) AND (a.Date < b.Date1)) GROUP BY b.Id) AS `ab` ON (a.Id = ab.Id) AND (a.Flag = 'Y')
WHERE a.Flag = 'Y' AND b.totalLinks > 0
LIMIT 0, 500
```

Try and also, `LIMIT` the DATA you want; this will reduce the filtering necessary by SQL.