# MySQL - using results of multiple subqueries with un-matching numbers of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know if this is possible but I'm trying to use the value from a MySQL `SELECT` query in multiple subqueries following the advice given at [How to specify the parent query field from within a subquery in mySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973246/how-to-specify-the-parent-query-field-from-within-a-subquery-in-mysql). There are unequal numbers of results in each subquery, which I suspect is why I can't get this working.

My DB is more complex than on the above post. I'm dealing with 5 tables which are as follows:

1. `substances` - a list of chemical substances, all of which have a unique ID (`substances.id`)
2. `ecs` - EC Number* values.
3. `cas` - CAS Number* values.
4. `ecs_substances` - Mapping `substances.id` to `ecs.id`. One `substances.id` may be mapped to **one, or more than one** `ecs.id`
5. `cas_substances` - Mapping `substances.id` to `cas.id`. One `substances.id` may be mapped to **one, or more than one** `cas.id`

** These are terms used for classifying chemicals.*

An example of how the data may look for 1 substance:

```
substances.id  | substances.name
-------------- | ----------------
1              | FooBar
```

An example of the assignment to multiple CAS numbers (the same principle applies for EC but am just using CAS for brevity):

```
cas_substances.id | substance_id
--------------------------------
997               | 1
----------------- | ------------
23423             | 1
--------------------------------
```

And then the CAS Numbers themselves:

```
cas.id | cas.value
------ | ---------
997    | ABC-123
------ | ---------
23423  | XYZ-876
------------------
```

The desired result is that I want to obtain a list of each `substances.id, substances.name` with a corresponding list of the CAS/EC Numbers, ideally formatted with a line break, e.g.

```
substances.id  | substances.name | cas_values         |
-------------- | --------------- | ------------------ |
1              | FooBar          | ABC-123 "\n" XYZ-876
```

I understand that the logic to be as follows:

1. `SELECT * FROM substances`
2. `SELECT * FROM cas_substances WHERE cas_substances.substance_id =` *Result(s) from 1 (`substances.id`)*
3. `SELECT cas.value FROM cas WHERE cas.cas.id =` *Result(s) from 2 (`cas_substances.cas_id`)*
4. Formatting to handle the fact there may (or may not) be multiple `cas_substances` rows - line break between records if there is.

I don't understand how to write the SQL that gets *Results from 1/2*.

Is it even possible to do this in MySQL? The application I'm building is written in PHP but I figured using SQL only will be far quicker than doing multiple subqueries in PHP (although it is much easier to write in PHP).

Comment: check a GROUP_CONCAT() and it should be fine with SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join these three tables together, then use `group by` and `group_concat` to achieve that.

```
select
    `sub`.*,
    group_concat(cas.`value` separator ' "\n" ') as cas_values
from substances `sub`
left join cas_substances cs on `sub`.id = cs.substance_id
left join cas on cas.id = cs.cas_id
group by `sub`.id
```

A [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40a23/3) here.

**Note:** [***`GROUP_CONCAT`***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) only works in mysql.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works. Is it possible to give an alias to `group_concat()` because in the returned data the column name is `group_concat(cas.`value` separator ' "\n" ') `. I also need to do the same for EC Number, so could do with the cols as `cas_values` and `ec_values` to make them easy to refer to for later on.

Comment: @Andy Alias is possible.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer works but I have expanded this to include all 5 tables:

```
select
`sub`.*,
group_concat(cas.`value` separator ' "\n" ') as cas_values,
group_concat(ecs.`value` separator ' "\n" ') as ecs_values
from substances `sub`
left join cas_substances cs on `sub`.id = cs.substance_id
left join cas on cas.id = cs.cas_id
left join ecs_substances ec on `sub`.id = ec.substance_id
left join ecs on ecs.id = ec.ec_id
group by `sub`.id
```