# LARAVEL ELOQUENT - I want to add column from user table to a relation table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am not much familiar with eloquent orm in laravel

I have 3 tables they are

```
 -- leads
       |
        Lead_appointments

   and users table
```

since lead_appointments belongs to leads references id on leads by lead_id

the leads_appointments has a column called created_by with user's  id in it

I am trying to query user's name and email along with the result as another column when query using eloquent

Lead Model

```
  class Leads extends Model
     { 
        public function appointments()
        {
           return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LeadsAppointments', 'lead_id');
        }
     }
```

My eloquent query in controller

```
   return $this->lead->with('appointments')->find($id);
```

the result is like this
[image]

In under appointments i also want user email and name along with created by in it

But I couldn't figure it out

Comment: "leads_appointments has a column called created_by with user's id" so you have User Model ok? and do you have any relation between User and appointments?

Comment: no relation is needed ,Actually I want to add user's email and name and id instead of created_by column as a columns @ChiragPatel

Answer (score 0):

Add a relation to `LeadAppointment` model like this:

```
class LeadAppointment extends Model
{ 
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'created_by');
  }
}
```

and change leads model like this:

```
 class Leads extends Model
     { 
        public function appointments()
        {
           return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LeadsAppointments', 'lead_id')->with('users');
        }
     }
```

Comment: You can access the columns by lead->user->email and similiar.

Comment: users id empty,

Comment: I need a result     |created-by|email|name| .   @SakiburRahuman

Comment: What is the result after you are running the query?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check if it is working now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973246/how-to-specify-the-parent-query-field-from-within-a-subquery-in-mysql like this in a relationship model @Sakibur Rahman