# Return COUNT from a sub query in the field list of a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

When I run the following query, I would like to include a field that returns the COUNT of the number of records in the sub query. The sub query however has a WHERE clause where a field in this clause must match a field in the parent query's SELECT statement:

```
SELECT id, firstName, lastName, 
COUNT(
   SELECT userId, address FROM UserDetails WHERE userId = <id_from_outer_select_statement>
)
FROM Users
```

It isn't clear to me how to apply the id field from the outer SELECT statement to the sub query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an alias to the table `Users` and use it to qualify the column `id` in the subquery:

```
SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserDetails WHERE userId = u.id) counter
FROM Users u
```

Comment: Is there a difference, at least in performance to your solution and the one by b.Muthamizhselvi? His places the COUNT outside the SELECT while yours is inside of it.

Comment: It is syntactically wrong to use count outside a query like that.

Comment: I came across this solution which is similar to yours although for MySql (not sure if it applies to Sqlite): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973246/how-to-specify-the-parent-query-field-from-within-a-subquery-in-mysql

Comment: It does apply to sqlite because it is standard sql. It is the same way I used select count(*) as an embedded query.

Comment: @forpas,Now why you edited your answer?. You posted wrongly as userId = <u.id. Did you copy of mine.

Comment: Because < was a typo, copy/paste from the OP's question and not copy/paste from someone else's answer.